# Is there a way to extract partial content from a tar.xz file?

Tags: tar, xz

I have a tar.xz file in a server. I would like to see what is inside and extract some of the content. The problem is that this file is 1.24TB large! My local PC can not hold it.

Is there a way to extract partial content from it?

Please notice that downloading the file in its entirely is out of the question.

Comment: Your PC doesn't *have to* save the file to work with its data. // Can't you work with the file server-side?

Comment: Yes, you can extract partial content on the server side provided you know the content location inside the XZ archive. `tar xvf <archive>.tar.xz <file1> <file2> ... <folder1> <folder2> ...` Even tab-completion works, to aid you select files/folders. Depending on number of files inside the archive & server capabilities it will take time.

Comment: Assuming that you do not know what is in it, I would run `tar tvfJ <archive>.tar.xz > <archive>_list.txt` and use the result for a file list. If it's large, you could always compress it.